# Correlation between request and response when sending soap message

Tags: c#, soap

My application is sending soap requests and of course receiving responses. Now I am trying to log that data to database but the problem is there is no correlation between request and response. I read that MessageHeaders.MessageId property might be helpful with that but app uses BasicHttpBinding which I guess does not support it (due to WSAddressing None, but I might be wrong). I can't change it to WSHttpBinding as project is written in .Net Core 2.2 which is not supporting it. Do you have any ideas? Maybe entirely different approach is desired? All I need is some id that will be the same for request and response.

EDIT:
It is crucial to mention that I am using IClientMessageInspector to log pure soap messages

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using IClientMessageInspector to log pure soap envelope so I guess it is not as easy as you described because BeforeSendRequest and AfterReceiveReply methods are not explicitly dependent

Comment: I actually just found CorrelationState argument of AfterReceiveReply method and I guess it might be it. I will come back with answer after checking that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that is exactly what correlationState argument is used for in AfterReceiveReply method. Everything is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-inspectors

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.